# Re-render the component when dialog closed

Tags: reactjs

```
                    <button className='plus' onClick={async () => {
                        await CustomDialog(<ServiceDetailsDialog />, {
                            title: 'Add Service Details',
                            showCloseIcon: true,
                        })
                    }}>&#43;</button>
```

How can I make the component rerenders to update data when this dialog closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CustomDialog must have an `onAfterClose` or something like that, and in that listener you can invoke [forceUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate)